# Angular universal: Route resolver + Firebase loading timeout

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, server-side-rendering

I am stuck with an issue and need assistance.
I have a component that waits for some Firebase/Firestore data to be resolved by a router resolver like below.

```js
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
    import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Resolve, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
    
    @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
    export class ArticleDataResolver implements Resolve<any> {
      constructor(
        private angularFirestore: AngularFirestore,
      ) { }
    
      resolve(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot
      ): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
        const stateKey = state.url;
        const ref = this.angularFirestore.collection("articles");
    
        return ref
          .doc(route.params.id)
          .get()
          .pipe(
            map((dataSnap) => {
              const articleData = dataSnap.data();
    
              return articleData;
            })
          );
      }
    }
```

In the consuming component, I have the subscription to the resolved observable data like below.

```js
    this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data);
      }
    );
```

This code works fine but stops working when a page is being refreshed or navigated to directly when being served with SSR using a cloud function as below.

```js
    export const ssr = functions.runWith({
      timeoutSeconds: 300,
      memory: "1GB"
    }).https.onRequest((request, response) => {
      require(`${process.cwd()}/dist/motif/server`).app(request, response);
    });
```

But the same code works with my Node/Express server even on page refresh and direct navigation. For testing locally, I use the following script: `npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr`

I am not sure what I am doing wrong because I do not get any errors but only cloud function timeout messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the exact answer, although I do know that a cloud function is not the appropriate way to serve a SSR application. Especially with a cold start you can have quite some lag in your page response, defeating the purpose of SSR.

However, as far as I know an `Observable` returned from a resolver needs to complete. You can find an entire discussion about this issue [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10556). This would mean you need to add a `take(1)` to your `pipe`:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ArticleDataResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(
    private angularFirestore: AngularFirestore,
  ) { }

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
    const stateKey = state.url;
    const ref = this.angularFirestore.collection("movementArticles");

    return ref
      .doc(route.params.id)
      .get()
      .pipe(
        map((dataSnap) => {
          const articleData = dataSnap.data();

          return articleData;
        }),
        take(1)
      );
  }
}
```

This however defeats the purpose of firestore as it doesn't update when you don't move back and forth from the route. You could do something like this:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ArticleDataResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(
    private angularFirestore: AngularFirestore,
  ) { }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> {
    const obs = this.angularFirestore.collection("movementArticles")
      .doc(route.params.id)
      .get()
      .pipe(
        map((snapshot) => snapshot.data(),
        shareReplay(1)
      );

    return obs.pipe(
      take(1),
      mapTo(obs)
    );
  }
}
```

Where you are actually setting an `Observable` as a result of the resolver, but only after it has returned once. I added a `shareReplay(1)`. Be aware though that the firestore collection won't be unsubscribed to because of this. You could add a `takeUntil` statement which checks for route changes to know when to unsubscribe from it.

You would need to consume in your component like this by accessing the `.snapshot` which will contain the observable you used in the `mapTo`:

```
this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data.subscribe(
  (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  }
);
```

Comment: Hi Poul, thank you for such a detailed answer.
I made the suggested changes but the data is returned as `undefined` in the component.

I have tried wrapping the resolver code to run outside of the Angular zone, that works but it stops working in the deployed version on firebase, it loads infinitely

Comment: When using `ng deploy --preview`  SSR works but does not work when deployed

Comment: @teebo does the SSR have access to the firestore data? Can you try adding a `catchError(() => of([]))` in the pipe?

Comment: I have found a temp solution and I cannot do another deployment as the current one works as I have noted that the solution you have shared helped and works with `ng deploy --preview` but does not work when deployed to firebase so I won't be able to check errors on the observable locally

Comment: I have come up with a solution; yours was very helpful and taught me but I ended up not using a resolver.
I have managed to set the meta tags in the component itself.

Can you please explain why it is not a good idea to use SSR with cloud functions?
And if you know; how can I have a working setup for a MEAN stack application with SSR and good SEO?

Will the server.ts file I have in the Angular project be enough to act as the server for the Front-end application and deploy it separately for example on a Digital ocean droplet?

Comment: I will accept your solution; but if you can please explain the above;
Thanks a lot Poul

Comment: @teebo can you update your question to include your solution by using meta tags? I'm curious.  About SSR, it depends on how you cache the generated html, or if you serve it directly. If you cache it, it can have a benefit for SEO, otherwise, there is not much of a difference. Also cloud functions have a cold start, which means that if the function hasn't been triggered recently, it has to start up the instance from scratch, which can take seconds. I can't tell you much about the `server.ts` and the digital ocean droplet. I guess it is, if that environment can handle TS files

Comment: Also, i can advise you to take a look at [scully](https://scully.io/docs/learn/overview/) for SSR + angular

Comment: I have posted another answer Poul to show the solution

Answer (score 0):

Because the goal was to have the meta tags set dynamically for each article; and because the resolver was taking me for a ride;
My solution is below without the resolver:

I have injected the state transfer service to my component constructor; which played a big rule in this solution

```
...// in the constructor
private state: TransferState
...

this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {
  this.selectedArticleID = params.id;

  this.zone.runOutsideAngular(
    () => {
      let ARTICLE_KEY = makeStateKey(`${this.selectedArticleID}`)
      this.selectedArticle = this.state.get(ARTICLE_KEY, null);

      const ref = this.angularFirestore.collection("articles");

      if (!this.selectedArticle) {
        this.subscriptions.add(
          ref
            .doc(this.selectedArticleID)
            .get()
            .subscribe((dataSnap) => {
              this.templateString = "";

              // do somethings
              // update meta tags
            })
        );
      } else {
        // update meta tags using the server data from the state
      }
    }
  );
});
```